# Xcode test coverage shows same target multiple times - one is always empty

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a project with SPM dependencies. Some of them are remote GitHub SPMs, like `Charts` and `DeviceKit`. Others are libraries from locally implemented Packages within the Xcode project file, e.g. `CMSData` on the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot from test coverage in Xcode]

When I run all my tests to see the test coverage, I get some of the targets multiple times, but the duplicated onces are always empty (there is no expand-arrow on the left of the title), like there are no files in them. They show up as 0% with no content, which is kind of frustrating. The target with the expand arrow does show the right test coverage and content, so I just want to get rid of the empty ones.

Is there any way to make sure that the targets only appears once and with the files in them?

Comment: If you find an answer please post I am dealing with this issue as well.

Comment: @Nobadi Unfortunately, I still have this issue... :-(